# Can I bake a Bump Map from a highpoly model?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, bump

I wonder if it's possible to bake a bump map from my high poly mesh to my lowpoly one?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
With Blender Render, in Bake Mode, select Displacement. It's basically the same as bump.

Comment: Hmm. Blender Internal renderer has long been depracated. Is there a way to do this in Blender 2.80?